# In the Jawbone UP API, is there any way to get daily step counts between a specified date range?

Tags: jawbone

*Reposting from the old UP API forum:*

I have a requirement to get the daily step count of the user within specified date ranges. Like for a particular user between the dates 1st june 2016 to 5th June 2016 , I want the step count on each day.  Based on what I have read the step count is part of the moves data which can be fetched for a day , but I didn't see any option to extract this data over a date range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [moves endpoint](https://jawbone.com/up/developer/endpoints/moves) to get a user's daily step counts over a date range. To do this, you should pass the `start_time` and `end_time` parameters with your request:

[image: Epoch timestamp parameters]

In the data returned, there is a list called `items`, and each item in this list has a `date` and a dictionary of `details`. Within `details`, the total step count for the day is called `steps`.

Here's a Python code snippet (oauth is a [`requests_oauthlib.OAuth2Session`](http://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2_workflow.html#web-application-flow) object:

```
>>> r = oauth.get('https://jawbone.com/nudge/api/v.1.1/users/@me/moves?start_time=1464739200&end_time=1465084800')

>>> rj = r.json()

>>> [(day['date'], day['details']['steps']) for day in rj['data']['items']]
[(20160531, 9643), (20160601, 8685), (20160602, 6888), (20160603, 6711)]
```